# How do I calculate free disk space on Windows in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows

I am creating a javascript project. And i want to calculate free disk space with percentage in Windows with javascript. Can you help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: use the title of your question in a search engine for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access any windows dlls from client side JavaScript application. Since JavaScript runs in browser of client machine on the other hand dlls runs on on the web server or server side machine.

All you need to write program on server side using any server side language I.e. Node and access disk space using this [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-disk-space), create a rest API and access it from your client program.